# I have received a word document with Walkman-Chanakya-905 font but unable to render the contents

Tags: fonts, ms-word, hindi

I have received a word document with Walkman-Chanakya-905 font but unable to render the contents. I am not able to locate the site from where I can download the correct font. Any help in this regards will be helpful.

Regards,

Krishna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the file rendered using the files from the site : https://sites.google.com/site/meribaaten/chankya-and-other-hindi-fonts